Why does changing the number of shares in a share split if there is only one class not require shareholder approval?
The book "Essay Exam Writing for the California Bar Exam" by Basick Schindler (2nd edition), discusses business associations. The book tells us that

"fundamental changes to the corporate business or structure must be approved with a majority shareholder vote.... some jurisdictions require the vote to be by a majority from all votes entitled to be cast, which is higher than the typical quorum rule."

The book goes on to tell us about the various types of fundamental changes. One such fundamental change is an amendment. On page 39, the book says:

"Amendment of articles or bylaws after shares have been issued
requires approval of the directors and shareholders and the
amendment must be filed with the state (no shareholder approval
needed to delete names of directors or agents, change company
name or corporate abbreviations (e.g., Inc. to Corp.), or to change
the number of shares in share split if only one class); if more than
one class of shares, then each class can vote as a group."

I have bolded the portion of the book that confuses me. What is a share split? Can there even be such a thing as a share split if there is only one class of shares? And why does it matter if there is only one class of shares? How is this any different from just increasing the number of shares in a company? And if it is no different then isn't that a big deal that shareholder definitely SHOULD get to vote on since it is a change to the maximum number of shares?
Help me understand the bolded portion. Address any of the questions I put in above if they are relevant. If they aren't relevant and based on a total misunderstanding (which I suppose is likely) help me understand why.
EDIT: While there is a similar question: What exactly changes following a stock split? Why doesn't "Shares" (on the following SEC balance sheet) change? I would like to clarify that this question is a bit different. While the linked question does address what a stock split is (which I now know is the same as a share split... I thought they were two different things), it does not address the issue with regards to why the classes of shares matter and how a stock split impacts shareholder rights. It does not address why increases the number of shares does not require shareholder approval.

This question is similar to: What exactly changes following a stock split? Why doesn't "Shares" (on the following SEC balance sheet) change?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@littleadv I agree that there is a similarity. I think the problem is that I did not really emphasize that I am looking at the issue of stock splits from the perspective of shareholder votes. I did edit my question. I hope you find the edit amenable. Had I known that a stock split is the same as a share split I probably would have asked the question differently.


What is a share split?

If a company decides that its price per share is getting too high, it can choose to split them.  For example, they could split each old share into two new ones.  Every existing shareholder will automatically get the new shares.

Can there even be such a thing as a share split if there is only one class of shares?

Yes.  See above.

And why does it matter if there is only one class of shares?

If there is only one class of share, then all shareholders will be treated equally by a split.  If there are several classes of shares, but only one class gets split, then the holders of those split shares end up with more shares, but the other shareholders don't.

How is this any different from just increasing the number of shares in a company?

It does increase the number of shares, but the existing shareholders get the new ones.  That's different from creating new shares and selling them off (which dilutes the holdings of the existing shareholders).
The important thing about a share split is it doesn't really change the status of existing shareholders.  Suppose a company has issued 1 000 000 shares, and the current value is $10 per share.  The company decides to do a two-for-one split.  There are now 2 000 000 shares, but the market will adjust their value down to $5 each.  Each shareholder now has twice as many shares, each worth half as much.

I love your answer. Your question makes it clear that the increase in the number of shares does not impact shareholder voting power and ownership interest in the corporation (assuming all classes are split in the same way). The nature of a share split is such that it is different from just increasing the number of shares willy nilly (which is prohibited without shareholder approval). Thank you!

But a reverse split does impact shareholder voting (due to fractional "new" shares getting cashed out)

@BenVoigt That's true, but generally a reverse split happens because the stock price is too low (typically NASDAQ's $1 requirement), so any reasonable reverse split ratio is going to impact individual shareholders by dollars to tens of dollars of voting rights, which is generally immaterial.

@user71659: When corporate ownership is on the line, the law ought to consider the possibility of unreasonable reverse split ratios.  For example, there's always a ratio that gives the plurality owner exclusive control.
